# In android app i create sockets with ip of cellular network it works but when i use wifi router ip is local like 192.168.23.2

Tags: android, sockets, networking

problem is ,
In android app i create sockets with ip provided with cellular network it works fine but does not work when i use wifi router as internet connection then its ip is local ip which is something like this 192.168.23.2 then sockets does not work from other networks

server send notification to mobile app works fine when there is cellular data network in mobile like 3g etc but 
when there is wifi or mobile is connected to router then its ip is usually something like this 192.168.12.5, and now if i send notification from server to this ip , now app is not able to receive notifications , i need to get the ip of mobile to be connectable from anywhere 
here is how i am sending data to ip

```
var net = require('net'); 
var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(3001, '192.168.8.101', function() {
   console.log('Connected');
   let data_call = {'type' : 'call' , 'user_ip' : '192.0.0.1', 'user' 
   : 'Pappa'}
   let data_msg = {'type' : 'msg' , 'user_ip' : '192.0.0.1', 'user' : 
   'Pappa', 'text' : 'i am good'}

   client.write(JSON.stringify(data_call));
   console.log('message sent');
   client.destroy();
```

});

Comment: it should work even if user and server are on different internet connections

Answer (score 0):

That is because 192.168.x.x is a local IP and unroutable to. You need to use the outfacing IP address of the router. Also you need to do port forwarding at your router.

Comment: no we can't do port forwarding as we only have android apk for users we can't configure their routers

Comment: If that is a commercial application, yes that is not possible. Why does the server initiate the communication? Client should reach the server (with a known and reachable IP address).

Comment: Otherwise, how do you even find your clients?

Comment: it is like , when client opens our app, we call server , and server saves its ip , and then when needed server sends messages to it, as my app has direct one to one chat between users

Comment: the thing i needed is, make one to one chat between users, without using any third party service, all should be customised  .

Comment: When client reaches you from behind its router, it can not have 192.168.x.x IP address. You should be able to communicate with the client using that IP for that session. However, when the session ends, client router most likely resets the NAT configuration; thus you can not use that IP and port to restart a session from the server side. Communication must always be initiated by the client.

Comment: yeah, i have also got a solution that we should keep sockets sessions alive in server , then we don't need to save ips, we just need sockets connections and then we can communicate directly